# Magento2 oauth2 integration

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, magento2

I am trying to integrate my third party application with Magento 2 for that am building an "oauth 2.0" login, but am unable to get the access token and I am working in postman

Getting the below error:

> oauth_consumer_key+is+a+required+field%2C+oauth_signature+is+a+required+field%2C+oauth_signature_method+is+a+required+field%2C+oauth_nonce+is+a+required+field%2C+oauth_timestamp+is+a+required+field%2C+oauth_token+is+a+required+field%2C+oauth_verifier+is+a+required+field

Please review the below screen cast

https://www.screencast.com/t/8MqTD9itlC2

Comment: just a suggestion: you're posting sensitive data in your screencast, you should be careful with that.

Comment: thank you i updated the screen cast

Comment: please mention clearly your problem

Comment: i want to use oauth 2.0 in Magento 2 how we do with google login in the similar way i want to create login with Magento application (client application) please suggest me what i have to pass in Authorization URL and token URL